# What changes are needed in .htaccess file when adding a sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

This is my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes 
Options FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Now for testing purpose I create another directory name `testproject` on live site. What should do I change in this current `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `RewriteBase` to

```
RewriteBase /testproject
```

Comment: when i click on -http://www.mysite.com/contact/ it open contact page.now i add directory testproject in which i put whole project ,I have made changes as per your guidence in this - testproject - directory's .htaccess file. but i not get output . please help me what to do? I did in local at my way but in live i can not understand this file